# Motorcycle Engine Vibration - Difference between left and right side

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, motors, measurements, vibration

I measured the vibration (jerk) on the left and right side of different motorcycles. I tested different engine types: Boxer engine, 3 cylinder, and V4. I measured the vibration on the same route, while driving for approx 30 minutes. I take the average jerk for every measurement. For every measurement the jerk on the right side of the motorcycle is higher than on the left side. I switched my sensors, since I thought this would be due to my sensors, but the results are the same. The difference is about 5-10%.

I'd thought that the vibration would be more or less symmetrical, but it seems to be different.

Could you think of a reason why the vibration differs?

**Edit**

Due to comments and answers here is some additional information:

- I ran the experiment with different participants on different motorcycles
- It seems that the difference of jerk occurred while standing, as well as driving (I cannot measure new data right now - but evaluated my existing datasets)
- [This is the route I used](https://goo.gl/PiyucD)
- The motorcycles used in this experiment are regular ones you can buy at any retailer

Comment: Are the motorcycles right/left symmetric?

Comment: Where did you place the sensors?

Comment: Do you get the same results, when you're not driving, but instead have the bike hooked up and with/without a gear selected, and without acceleration?

Comment: @DLS3141 more or less, yes. These are normal motorcycles, that you can buy. Really nothing special here. For example one bike might have the exhaust on the right side and the chain on the left side.

Comment: @willpower2727 They were placed at different positions of the motorcycle (e.g. handle bar).

Comment: @ott-- Right now I cannot run the experiment, but I tried to extract the parts where the participant is just sitting on the motorcycle with the started engine, and yes, jerk on the right side is higher than on the left side.

Comment: @Robin "More or less" could easily mean a difference of 5-10%

Comment: @DLS3141 well I mean it's hard to answer that type of question. I haven't built the motorcycles that were tested. Typically motorcycles are built to have equal weight on both sides. For example one motorcycle that was tested was a Yamaha Tracer 900, another was a Triumph Daytona 675. What's interesting ist that all face more vibration on the right side. Therefore, I think it should be independent from the model but depend on something else.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few variables that you seemingly haven't fully considered when running this experiment. It was a good idea to change the sensors to test any discrepancies there, but you also should consider your route and your riding/bio-mechanics.

For example if you ride the same route every time, but are constantly turning left, one side is going to jerk more than the other due to the weight distribution. Or if you naturally lean more to one side than the other while riding.

I would keep working to disprove this hypothesis, instead of thinking of reasons why it exists, and when you get more supporting evidence, go back to the drawing board.

I think a good test would be 5 minutes (not including acceleration) on level, paved road. Bring some friends/whoever along and have everyone do this ride a couple times. (A convenience sample isn't always a good representation of the actual 'population' but at least it'll remove some of the questions regarding your riding style.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I did that experiment with different drivers (forgot to add that to the question). You could have a point with the route, overall the route should be more or less equal, however it is a round-trip where you go right. Overall, I wondered if there could be a mechanical reason for the vibration difference?